# Next Js context parameter from getStaticProps returns "{ locales: undefined, locale: undefined, defaultLocale: undefined }"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am simply trying to use the context parameter from Next Js's getStaticProps function, but when I console log it, I get "{ locales: undefined, locale: undefined, defaultLocale: undefined }".

I use getStaticProps inside the pages folder as I am supposed to but I still get that weird object on all pages.

I would really appreciate any help as I was not able to find any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally normal, it's part of [Next.js i18n routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)

- `locale` contains the active locale (if enabled).
- `locales` contains all supported locales (if enabled).
- `defaultLocale` contains the configured default locale (if enabled).

Don't worry about it if you are not using internationalisation.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My issue is that it only returns "{ locales: undefined, locale: undefined, defaultLocale: undefined }". I no longer get "params". Do you know why that is?

Comment: `params` are only passed there if you are using dynamic route and `getStaticPaths` as an addition to `getStaticProps`. Maybe you forgot to use `getStaticPaths`? Or your route is not dynamic? More info https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths

Comment: Indeed, my route was not dynamic. I should have read the documentation more carefully. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it!